# Interchanging infinite integrals and limits proof

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $(f_n)$, $f, g$ are regulated functions on $[0, R]$ for every $R > 0$ and satisfy:
$(i) f_n → f$ uniformly on $[0, R]$, $(ii) |fn(x)| ≤ g(x)$ on $[0, ∞)$, and (iii) $\int_0^∞ g  \,$ is convergent

Show that the improper integral  $\int_0^∞ f  \,$ exists and $\int_0^∞ f_n  \,$ $→$$\int_0^∞ f  \,$ as $n → ∞$

I can prove it for bounds $a$ and $b$ but I can't figure it out for the infinite integral

Comment: Regulated means?

Answer (score 0):

So $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ pointwise and we have by the inequality that $|f_{n}(x)|\leq|g(x)|$ that $|f(x)|\leq g(x)$, so $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}|f|\leq\int_{0}^{\infty}g<\infty$.

Now given $\epsilon>0$, some $R$ is such that $\displaystyle\int_{R}^{\infty}g<\epsilon$. And we have $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{R}f_{n}\rightarrow\int_{0}^{R}f$. Note that $\displaystyle\int_{R}^{\infty}|f_{n}|+|f|<2\epsilon$.